# Mysql view - Select data in join returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, view

I would appreciate some help with MySQL.

Here is a part of my schema (the first table is called "sites") :
[db_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2KMp.png)

sites.contractor is linked to companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson

I'm building a view in order to gather some information from the two tables.
I need to put sites.latitude, sites.longitude and a contractor name (companiesornaturalperson.name) into my view.

So I wrote :

```
CREATE VIEW `data_entry` AS
SELECT        
    `sites`.`longitude` AS longitude,
    `sites`.`latitude` AS latitude,

    (SELECT `companiesornaturalperson`.`name` 
        FROM  sites sites
        INNER JOIN 
            companiesornaturalperson companiesornaturalperson ON sites.contractor = companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson
    ) AS contractor_name

FROM sites
```

When I have one row in my site table, this is working well but when I have more than a row, that leads me to "subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

I understood that it was because my join is bringing more than one value in those cases. The problem is that I don't know how to return only one value (some kind of "WHERE sites.id = real id of the site"). I did many searches but I still can't solve it.

Comment: What should it return if multiple contractors exist?  Are you only wanting to return 1 per lat/long?

Comment: There will only be one contractor associated to each site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want -- probably -- with a correlated subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW `data_entry` AS
    SELECT s.`longitude` AS longitude,
           s.`latitude` AS latitude,
           (SELECT cnp.`name` 
            FROM companiesornaturalperson cnp 
            WHERE s.contractor = cnp.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson
           ) AS contractor_name
    FROM sites s;
```

This might still generate an error, if there were more than one match (unlikely, given the names of the columns).

MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `FROM` clause, but scalar subqueries are allowed.

You can also do this with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
CREATE VIEW `data_entry` AS
    SELECT s.`longitude` AS longitude,
           s.`latitude` AS latitude,
           cnp.`name` as contractor_name
    FROM sites s LEFT JOIN
         companiesornaturalperson cnp 
         ON s.contractor = cnp.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson;
```

Comment: I will try your first solution. I can't do the second because I will need to had more columns from "companiesornaturalperson" table into the select : one with ON sites.contractor = companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson; one other with ON sites.landlord = companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson...

Comment: Ok, the first solution works pretty well. Thank you for, life saver !

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
CREATE VIEW `data_entry` AS
SELECT        
    `sites`.`longitude` AS longitude,
    `sites`.`latitude` AS latitude,
    `companiesornaturalperson`.`name` 
FROM sites    
INNER JOIN 
    companiesornaturalperson ON sites.contractor = companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson
```

Comment: Yes but I will need to had more columns from "companiesornaturalperson" table into the select : one with ON sites.contractor = companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson; one other  with ON sites.landlord = companiesornaturalperson.idCompaniesOrNaturalPerson...